# Authentication in Rails, where to start?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im learning Rails by building apps.

I want to make my first authenticated app: users signup, login, do some changes in models they have access to and logout.

I did the Google search but it is quite confusing: many plugins, many tutorials. Don't know where to start.

Is there a state-of-the-art authentication method for Rails? What do you use in Production to authenticate your users?

Any help in this will be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

+1 to Jason, -1 to NSD and sparky. Authentication system is *not* the thing you want to build yourself, at least if you're aiming for production use. It's like inventing your own encryption algorithm - it's a lot more safe to use something extensively tested and well-developed.

I've also been using authlogic, but there are some alternatives over there - like the good old [restful authentication](http://github.com/technoweenie/restful-authentication), and [devise](http://github.com/plataformatec/devise), which I guess is more modern so to speak. BTW the [two](http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise) [latest](http://railscasts.com/episodes/210-customizing-devise) railscasts are devoted to devise.

Comment: Is it still "more safe" when that extensively tested solution everyone is running because they believed it was well-developed has an exploit published that compromises thousands of systems? Homogeneity breeds extinction, and if anyone had proven otherwise, there would probably be an officially sanctioned authentication system in the framework.

Comment: @NSD: Well sir, if you are able to build your own system with zero chance of exploitation, that's good for you, and I take off my hat to you. But a lot of humble developers like me realize that it's a bit over their heads (and for the same reason when we need public-key cryptography, we just use RSA. Of course if it's broken we're in trouble, but what could be broken faster - RSA or my self-invented algorithm?). Regarding your last sentence, my post probably shows that there's no homogeneity in the world of authentication for rails.

Answer (score 5):

I've used [authlogic](http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic) in the past and have been quite happy with it.  Ryan has a railscast (video tutorial) for authlogic [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/160-authlogic).

Answer (score 0):

If your application is simple and just want a simple and secure user login page you might want to look into the  [Restful Authentication](http://github.com/technoweenie/restful-authentication) plugin. Its very easy to use and if you don't have much authentication requirements this should do fine.

```
script/plugin install git://github.com/technoweenie/restful-authentication.git
script/generate authenticated user sessions
rake db:migrate
```

You can find out more by checking out this excellent [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/67-restful-authentication).

Answer (score 0):

As A beginner I would recommend Restful Authentication as its simple to set up and will get you up and running with no time

following is a step by step guid

http://avnetlabs.com/rails/restful-authentication-with-rails-2

and authlogic - (http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic) is another great plug in which is more flexible but requires some work to implement user registration and  stuff

cheers,
sameera

Answer (score -1):

One man's state-of-the-art authentication system is another man's worthless pile of garbage. You're almost always better off rolling your own in the long run. O'Reilly's Ruby Cookbook has some extremely basic examples that will set you off in the right general direction, then you can decide whether or not other people's solutions are right for you.

Comment: While I disagree that you're "almost always better off rolling your own in the long run", I do think this reply is worth upvoting. I think it's a good exercise to write your own early on. Once you have intermediate requirements, you can switch to a popular plugin, then when you have expert requirements you can change to your own, now more advanced authentication system.

Answer (score -1):

I would agree with NSD.  Figuring out the plugins & how they should mesh with your application to me longer than creating an auth system in my latest application.

My tips - create a user_sessions controller and use normal CRUD methods to handle creating/destroying (ie logging in & out). Create another model for the user - it can handle create accounts & updating (ie changing passwords).  Stick a :before_filter on each controller which needs protection.